# Writing a formula of a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose Joe owns a cafeteria. He has 30 sandwiches and 20 salads. The salads are located in the back of the store in the refrigerator. One person picks a meal at a time (obviously without replacement). Joe continues to sell sandwiches until he has to walk to the back of the store to get a salad. Let $X$ be the number of orders sold on which the first salad is sold. How could I write $P(X=x)$ as a formula?

I've started doing the following:

$P(X=1) = 20/50$

$P(X=2) = (30/50) * (20/49)$

$P(X=3) = (30/50) * (29/49) * (20/48)$

$P(X=4) = (30/50) * (29/49) * (28/48) * (20/47)$

How can I express $P(X=x)$ as a formula?

Comment: The numbers you give are based on the assumption that each customer picks a meal randomly from amongst those remaining available.  A much more likely scenario would appear to me to be for successive customers make their choices independently with some fixed probability of $\ p\ $ of choosing a sandwich, and $\ 1-p\ $ of choosing a salad (at least until either item ran out).  The formula for $\ P\ $ would then be $$ P(X=n)=\cases{p^{n-1}(1-p)&for $n<31$\\p^{30}&for $n=31$ }$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n=1,2,\ldots,30$ we have
$$
\mathbb P(X=n) = \frac{20}{50-n+1}\prod_{j=0}^{n-2} \frac{30-j}{50-j}
$$
and for $n=31$,
$$
\mathbb P(X=31) = \frac{1}{47129212243960}.
$$
(I believe this is correct, at least.)

Answer (score 1):

Separate the calculation of salad and sandwich respectively.

For salad, we can see that when,

$x=1$, it is $\frac{20}{50}$.

$x=2$, it is $\frac{20}{49}$.

So from here, when $x=k$, it will be $\frac{20}{50-(k-1)}$

For sandwich, we can see that when,

$x=1$, it is $1$.

$x=2$, it is $\frac{30}{50}$.

$x=3$, it is $\frac{30}{50}\frac{29}{49}$.

$x=4$, it is $\frac{30}{50}\frac{29}{49}\frac{28}{48}$.

So, from here, we can see that when $x=1$, the first term $1$, this means that $k-1=0$ (the starting value). Hence,

$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{30-i}{50-i}$

Combine both of them, we have

$P(X=x) = \frac{20}{50-(x-1)}\prod_{i=0}^{x-1} \frac{30-i}{50-i}$